# Spring integration messages are only serializing after some reaching some capacity causing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: spring-integration, gemfire

We are having problem with spring integration messages serialization.We are GemFire as our message store. When we have more than 10k messages we are seeing inconsistent results.
 I have a class like this

```
{public class SplitReportInformationImpl implements Comparable {
       private transient List<Comparable> sortFields;
       public SplitReportInformationImpl(List<Comparable> sortFields) {
          this.sortFields = sortFields;
       }

     @Override
       public int compareTo(SplitReportInformation o2) {
             // here NullPointException
             for (int k =0; k < getSortFields().size(); k++) { 
             int result = getSortFields().get(k)
                                        .compareTo(o2.getSortFields()
                                        .get(k));
             if (result != 0) {
                return result;
             }
          }
          return 0;
       }
     }}
```

We are getting NullPointerException in the compareTo method for getSortFields().size(). There are thousands of jsons being read sequentially and one Message  is create per json and SplitReportInformationImpl object is created for each json and stored in the message.

There is aggregator which combines the messages and that aggregator calls the above compareTo method. That's where it results in NullPointException. Code is little bit complicated not easy to put here and not useful this bug since the SplitReportInformationImpl object is created way before the aggregator.

There are two sets of jsons one set contains 9k jsons and other contains 3k jsons. If 9k jsons are inputted first then they all produce right output with out  any error and if the 3k jsons are inputted straight after then it throws NullPointException for some of them as explained above.

My question is that if spring messages are serializing the messages it should always serialize and it should always through NullPointException since the sortField variable is transient.

If Spring messages are not serialized at all then we should not get NullPointException at all.

Comment: Never seen that before. It is indeed an issue with `transient` and Java serialization, but since you say it is not so consistent, then it comes with Gemfire somehow. Maybe when the data is stored to the local cache, there is no any serialization, but when it goes to the replication, a `transient` property is cleared. We definitely need a minimal code to play and reproduce. Although you still need to think to change your logic without `transient`

Comment: Could you load only the 3k json and let us know what happens ?